# ¿Problema con class, error con ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter

> 1. He conseguido acercarme al final sin embargo al momento de iniciar la segunda y ultima ventana
>    esta el eeror en donde no se como adaptar el class para que se muestre en la segunda ventana y asi
>    que se muestre el cronometro.
> 2. Intento hacer que el condicionar de abrir ventana 2 se una con el class sin embargo no se como, ademas que la parte de class la copie de una pagina web porque era lo que me faltaba. Les dejo link de donde lo saque:

https://progexpertos.com/q/21294/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-out-of-a-python-tkinter-clock

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import datetipe
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def times():
    current_time=time.strftime("%I:%M:%S") 
    clock.config(text=current_time,bg="black",fg="green",font="Arial 50 bold")
    clock.after(200,times)

def validar():
    if entrada1.get()== "123":
        abrirv2()
    else: 
        messagebox.showwarning("Lo siento", "clave incorrecta")

def abrirv2():
    ventana.withdraw()
    win=tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry("900x900")
    win.configure(background="dark blue")
    win.title("Ventana 2")

    e3=tk.Label(win,text="Tomate un tiempo",
    bg="orange", fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
    countdown = Countdown(win)
    countdown.pack()

     class Countdown(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
       super().__init__(master)
       self.create_widgets()
       self.show_widgets()
       self.seconds_left = 0
       self._timer_on = False

   def show_widgets(self):

    self.label.pack()
    self.entry.pack()
    self.start.pack()

   def create_widgets(self):

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="00:00:00")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, justify='center')
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.start = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_button)

   def countdown(self):
       
        self.label['text'] = self.convert_seconds_left_to_time()

        if self.seconds_left:
            self.seconds_left -= 1
            self._timer_on = self.after(1000, self.countdown)
       else:
            self._timer_on = False

    def start_button(self):
    
        self.seconds_left = int(self.entry.get())   # 1. to fetch the seconds
        self.stop_timer()                           # 2. to prevent having multiple
        self.countdown()                            #    timers at once

    def stop_timer(self):
        '''Stops after schedule from executing.'''
        if self._timer_on:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer_on)
            self._timer_on = False

    def convert_seconds_left_to_time(self):

        return datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.seconds_left)

def cerrarv():
    ventana.destroy()


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Ventana 1")
ventana.geometry("900x900")

ventana.configure(background= "dark blue")
ventana.title("Reloj digital con Tkinter")
clock=Label(ventana,font=("times",50,"bold"))
clock.pack(pady=25,padx=100)
times()

digi=Label(ventana,text=" Hora Actual",font="times 24 bold",fg="red")
digi.pack()

e1=tk.Label(ventana,text="Password:",bg= "dark turquoise",fg="white")
e1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
entrada1=tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

boton3=tk.Button(ventana,text="Validar password",fg="blue",command=validar)
boton3.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo quieres que se muestre la segunda ventana? Ahora se muestra sólo cuando se cierra la primera; mostrando la hora, un input y un botón para validar la contraseña.

Comment: En la primera ventana esta el validar contraseña y la hora, lo que quiero es que en la segunda pantalla despues de ingresar la contraseña porque ese es el condicional, se muestre una nueva etiqueta en donde puedas ajustar el cronometro .marcha atras

Comment: Si deseas que te salga el cronómetro en la segunda ventana, eliminas lo que tienes puesto en `if __name__ == '__main__':`. En `def abrirv2():` , debajo de `e3.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, fill=tk.X)`, agregas `countdown = Countdown(win)` y luego `countdown.pack()`

Comment: Listo casi lo consigo ahora por laguna razon hay un error en el class countdown. miren el codigo editado.

Comment: A mí no me da error. Eso sí, tuve que cambiar `import datetipe` por `import datetime` y arreglar la indentación de algunas líneas de código.

Comment: Lo logre, muchas gracias.

Comment: Es bastante satisfactorio.